# En SQL Server cómo comparo la estructura de dos bases de datos para encontrar diferencias

Tags: sql-server

Ambas bases tienen la misma cantidad de objetos pero por alguna razón me dice que son distintas. Alguna diferencia debe haber. **¿Con qué comando SQL Server puedo hacer la comparación?**

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede hacer useo de herramientas de Visual Studio como SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) para comparar esquemas de base de datos, tal como se explica [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver16#compare-schemas-with-the-visual-studio-automation-model). SSDT para Visual Studio puede ser descargado para instalación desde [este enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16).